# Keeping HTML in Django email templates DRY

Tags: html, django

I have created Django html email templates that looks something like this:

```
<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6em; font-weight: normal; margin: 10px 0 10px; padding: 0;">
        Hello John
    </p>

<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6em; font-weight: normal; margin: 10px 0 10px; padding: 0;">
        Welcome to the site
    </p>

<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6em; font-weight: normal; margin: 10px 0 10px; padding: 0;">
        More text here...
    </p>
```

Since it's an email template, I must use inline styles and as a result it looks ugly and I have to repeat myself. I'm looking for a way to improve this.

My idea is to create a template tag that will return the style info:

```
@register.filter
def style(tag):
    tags = {
        'p': "style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6em; font-weight: normal; margin: 10px 0 10px; padding: 0;""
# Will add more options here
        }
    return tags[tag]
```

Then in my template I will use:

```
<p|style>
        Hello John
    </p>

<p|style>
        Welcome to the site
    </p>

<p|style>
        More text here...
    </p>
```

I know it is not ideal to put html in python code, but I can't think of a better way?
Any thoughts or better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining a CSS class and assigning this class to all the elements that need to be formatted.

**template.css**

```
 .MyEmailStyle {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: 1.6em; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    margin: 10px 0 10px; 
    padding: 0;
 }
```

**main.html**

```
<p class="MyEmailStyle">
    Hello John
</p>
```

As you can't include external or internal CSS files in an email template, consider using this [library](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss).

Comment: The way I understand it is I can't add css files to email templates, it has to be inline styles. Or is this incorrect?

Comment: @Johan: there also is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-premailer as an alternative to _django-inlinecss_, having never use the later I can't compare them but I have never had to complain about _premailer_.  _premailer_ provides the additional feature of making URLs absolutes

Comment: I tried both, `django-premailer` doesn't support external CSS. and `django-inlinecss` thrown exception `No match was found. We're done or something is broken`  from its dependency `pynliner`. Unfortunately, both did not work for me.